# How do I implement two abstract methods in Java using lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, interface, functional-programming, java-8

I have a Functional Interface in the code below which has one abstract method and one object method override. So when I write Lambda expression for that , how can I implement my equals method.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddToString test = a -> (a + " End");
        out.println(test.stringManipulation("some string"));
        out.println(test.increment(5));
        out.println(test.equals(null));
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface AddToString {
    String stringManipulation(String a);
    default int increment(int a) { return a+1; }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj);
}
```

One way to do that is to create Anonymous class like given below, but is there a better method using lambda expressions -

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddToString test = new AddToString() {
            public String stringManipulation(String a) {
                return a + " End";
            }
            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object Obj) {
                //Just testing whether it overrides
                return 5==5;
            }
        };
        out.println(test.stringManipulation("some string"));
        out.println(test.increment(5));
        out.println(test.equals(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: How should a plausible lambda expression based `equals` implementation, which can’t access `this` nor any of the interface’s methods look like? Even an anonymous class based implementation is hard to imagine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. If you need to override `equals`, you'll need to create a class (anonymous or otherwise), you can't do it with a lambda.